# Air mouse for Android, which sensor?

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm working on an app that uses the smartphone to control the pointer on a desktop. I saw many app of this type on the store so I know it isn't impossible! I'm doing this for university, I'm not looking for the perfect app but I can't figure which sensor should I use... I tried to use the rotation vector sensor and it's good for pitch (y values of pointer) but not the same for azimuth (for the x axis)... I didn't filter values. Do you think I have to change sensor or is it just a matter of filtering data? Any tips?

EDIT: Gyro mouse in Ali's video is really smooth and accurate and it says it's very simple to do but not for me! I take the rotation Matrix, get the angle change and then I map it to pixels but it's very inaccurate (the azimuth)! I'll post the code to show clearly what I'm doing:

```
//get values from Rotation Vector sensor
SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, sensorValues);
SensorManager.getAngleChange(orientationValues, rotationMatrix, prevMatrix);
prevMatrix = rotationMatrix;
azimuth += orientationValues[0];
pitch += orientationValues[1];

//getAngleChange returns radians so I multiply by 100
float dX = (azimuth - lastX)*100.f;
float dY = (pitch - lastY)*100.f;
pixel.x += dX;
pixel.y += dY;

// store values
lastX = azimuth;
lastY = pitch;
prevMatrix = rotationMatrix;
```

Comment: what about accelerometer?

Comment: @PozzoApps: too inaccurate for orientation

Comment: It wasn't an answer, just a comment, I am curious also, thats why I up voted your question =]

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work on your device. I see inefficiencies in your code snippet (superfluous variables and unnecessary assignments) but I don't see any bug in it. I think what you are doing is correct. Does your device have gyroscopes? Is the sensor fusion working properly on your device? If your rotation vector is messed up then the gyro mouse won't work well either.

Comment: Please try it with [this code snippet](https://gist.github.com/baharev/ca5d658eae72cf063bbd). I removed the inefficiencies and added some notes that might worth trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is most likely the [**gyro mouse**](http://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=37m5s). Basically, you just accumulate the *change* in angles along each axis. Code snippet is also given in the linked video.

---

**UPDATE:** Yes, you need sensor fusion. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the Android API or with the Android sensors so I can only *guess*. I would try the [`SensorManager.getRotationMatrix()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getRotationMatrix%28float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d%29) to get the rotation matrices, then determine the change of angle with [`SensorManager.getAngleChange()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getAngleChange%28float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d%29). Then you just accumulate the change along each axis.

Comment: Doesn't it use only gyroscopes right? He's talking about sensor fusion... Rotation vector is a composite sensor, so isn't it better than just gyroscopes?

Comment: I added code to my question, I still don't understand which sensor is used by the gyro mouse in the video because my rotation vector (sensor fusion) is very inaccurate!

Comment: @Ali i didn't find code snippet with the linked video

Comment: @AkashKumar The part with the snippet starts at 38:00. You still have to figure out how to do the same in your setting / with your SDK. Good luck!